# Rails: Restfully Deleting by database field (delete=1) instead of removing from DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Just wondering if there's a simple way to restfully delete entries by updating a database field instead of dropping the entry from the database?

Specifically, I'd like to trigger "deleted=1" instead of "drop from database" whenever a RESTful "delete" function can be run.

Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: like a boolean attribute marked on the attribute so it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to do a bunch of work in the controllers when you can control everything in the model. Add a deleted_at column to your model, override the destroy() method, then set your default_scope to where(:deleted_at => nil).

Do all this, of course, only if you don't want to use acts_as_paranoid ([github](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid), [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_paranoid)).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I'd probably create a `destroy` method on the controller and implement the desired bevahior there.

Answer (score 0):

I do this for stuff I don't want to destroy. Lots of apps do this for users, so they don't destroy the information but really disable the account.

1. `rails g migration add_deleted_boolean_to_model`
2. add the code in Part 2 into the migration
3. rake `db:migrate`
4. ad the code in Part 3 into the controller

Part 2 - In your migration file:

```
add_column :modle_name, :deleted, :boolean, :default => false
```

Then `rake db:migrate`

Part 3 - In your controller:

```
def destroy
    @object = Model.find(params[:id)
    @object.update_attribute(:deleted, true)
end 

def index
    @objects = Object.find(:all, :conditions => ['deleted=?', false])
end

def show
    @object = Model.find(params[:id)
    @object = nil if @object.deleted
    flash[:notice] = "Sorry that was deleted; contact admin if you want it resated"
end
```

Keep in mind the find conditions are not rails3, maybe someone will edit that.